# How to change UINavigationBar of UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have added `UINavigationController` to Storyboard and the root is a `UIViewController` which contains a `UIView` that has `WKWebView` I want to hide the `UINavigationBar` y axis or the height so it hides using animations when I scroll up what is the best practice ? and can you please provide a sample code (only what values should I change not the whole process) ? should I change `UINavigationBar` frame or use `NSLayoutConstraints`

currently I change hide it this way:

```
func setNavigationBarHeightWith(duration: TimeInterval, navHeight: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {

        self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y = navHeight
        self.containerTopConstraint.constant = navHeight - 20
        self.urlField.alpha = alpha
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: navigationController.hidesBarOnSwipe = true

Comment: Look into the navigationController its setNavigationBarHidden(_: Bool, animated: Bool) method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621885-setnavigationbarhidden?language=objc

Comment: the problem with this is that it hides the UINavigationBar completely and the WKWebView will start under the status bar from the beginning of screen I want it be always below the status bar @ocanal

Comment: @LloydKeijzer same response to you mate

Comment: @Raffi, so why don't you set your wrapper view's top constraint to layout guide?

Comment: because changing the constant of the top constraint is not working as expected... here is what I do

            self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y = navHeight
            self.containerTopConstraint.constant = navHeight - 20
            self.urlField.alpha = alpha
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: I have updated the question with the code so it is more readable